# Dragdrop Trash Can

Tags: pantheon-files, language

Does the trash docklet has a dragdrop functionality?
Also the language of the Trash docklet stays in English and doesn't change to Dutch in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is hard to find a use for it since there is no desktop from which to drag file items in elementary.  You can drag file items from Files but that is pointless as it has its own Trash icon and also results in no "Undo" action.  The same goes for dragging items out of e.g. Photos or Music - I am not sure what it does to the databases of those apps and there is no way of undoing the action except by opening Files, finding the items in the trash and restoring them manually.

The docklet is now intended mainly for seeing how much is in the bin, seeing what was recently trashed, opening the trash and emptying the trash.